# Константное поле объекта

Tags: c++

```
class Triangle
{
    int a;
    const char name[] = "Треугольник";
    бла бла бла
};
```

Можно в конструкторе написать инициализировать переменную, но мне интересно можно ли как-то избежать этого.

Answer (score 2):

Не надо использовать константные поля (в т.ч. поля-ссылки) в объектах.

Причина проста - нельзя написать перемещающий оператор присваивания, а значит нельзя написать swap.

Инварианты класса можно обеспечивать и без константных полей. Можно делать константные методы, фабрика может возвращать константную ссылку на класс или `shared_ptr<const X>`. Внутренности класса и так защищены с помощью `private:`, так что достаточно обеспечить правильный интерфейс, и инварианты нельзя будет поломать снаружи. А уж реализацию класса можно просто прокрыть тестами.

Comment: Несемантично. Я бы скорее отказался от оператора присваивания, чем нарушил семантику поля.

Comment: В принципе, какая угодно. Имя этого объекта или там id этого объекта. А почему спрашиваете?

Comment: Память-то всегда скопировать можно, а потом уже разбираться со внутренностями. А для копирования памяти контантность ничего значить не будет.
@VladD, зря.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, хм. Копирование памяти при наличии константного поля мне кажется должно быть UB. Т. к. оптимизатор вправе считать, что константное поле не может поменяться.

Comment: @VladD Ну если оно каким-то образом инициализируется так, что разные объекты имеют в нём разные значения, то заинлайнить значение на этапе компиляции невозможно. Если будут какие-то выкрутасы с этим полем в методе, который выполнил копирование, то действительно может быть что-то не то (например, значение скопируется компилятором в локальную переменную). Но, в остальных случаях, например, если речь идёт о вызовах методов объектов, не вижу причин ожидать какой-то подвох. Но да, осторожность проявить не помешает.

Comment: Хм.. а ведь метод может и заинлайниться... Но всё равно, в перемещающем операторе вряд ли есть что-то выходящее за рамки набора присваиваний и обнулений, так что именно в нём вероятность наткнуться на что-то плохое мне кажется близкой к нулю.

Answer (score 1):

В С++ есть всего два способа инициализации константных полей: путем field-like инициализации при объявления поля (1) или в блоке инициализации (2).

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(int n)
    {}
};

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
        : another_("foo") // инициализация констант
        , my_(42)         // в блоке инициализации
    {}
private:
    const int n_ = 42; //field-like инициализация
    const std::string str_ = "foo"; // field-like инициаилацзия
    const std::string another_;
    const MyClass my_; // в этом случае, field-like инициализация невозможна
};
```

Константное поле - это лучший способ обеспечения [инварианта объекта](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_invariant), т.е. некоторого условия, которое должно быть истинным на протяжении всего времени жизни объектов.

Константные поля еще используются для получения [неизменяемых объектов](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), что позволяет безопасно шарить объекты в многопоточном окружении.

Comment: Почему бы `const int n_` и `const string str_` не сделать статическими членами класса, раз их значения известны на этапе компиляции?

Comment: Исходный вопрос не совсем ясен, поэтому ответ тоже не слишком точен. В некоторых случаях, константные объекты могут иметь значения по умолчанию и инициализироваться лишь в одном конструкторе. В этом случае, константные поля должны быть экземплярными. В противном случае - статическими.

Comment: @Abyx , а автор ответа и не утверждает обратное. Константность в C++ - это один из способов получить иммутабельность и инвариантность. Иммутабельные интерфейсы тоже, но за них нужно платить в рантайме. Константность - бесплатна.

Comment: @Sergey Teplyakov, комментарий к `const MyClass my_;` не соответствует действительности, уберите его. Иницализация возможна и ничем не отличается от той, что Вы привели для `std::string`